# How to find whether unique key constraint exists for given columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am working on a perl script, where i need to run update queries. But I need to check if the update sql command does not violate unique key constraint. 
So if I have a table `tb(C1,C2,C3)` and my update query is like:

```
update tb set C1='b1' where C2='a1' ;
```

Is there a way to find if a unique key constraint exist for column `C1,C2` *before* trying to update? Ie: `UNIQUE(C1,C2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query the [system catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalogs.html) for **unique constraints**, in particular `pg_constraint` and `pg_attribute`:

```sql
SELECT c.conname, pg_get_constraintdef(c.oid)
FROM   pg_constraint c
JOIN  (
   SELECT array_agg(attnum::int) AS attkey
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = 'tb'::regclass  -- table name optionally schema-qualified
   AND    attname  = ANY('{c1,c2}') 
   ) a ON c.conkey::int[] <@ a.attkey AND c.conkey::int[] @> a.attkey
WHERE  c.contype  = 'u'
AND    c.conrelid = 'tb'::regclass;
```

- The [object identifer type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) `regclass` helps to unambiguously  identify your table.
- The system catalog information function [`pg_get_constraintdef()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html) gets you nicely formatted information, which is not strictly necessary for your request.
- Also using [array operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) `<@` and `@>` to make sure the arrays match completely. (The order of columns is unknown.) The system columns are `smallint` and `smallint[]` respectively. Cast to `integer` to make it work with those operators.
- Column names are case sensitive when looking them up in the system catalog directly. If you didn't double-quote `C1` and `C2` at creation time, you have to use `c1` and `c2` in this context.
- There could also be a multicolumn **primary key constraint** enforcing uniqueness. To cover that in the query use instead:

  ```sql
  WHERE  c.contype IN ('u', 'p')
  ```

Building on @Roman's fiddle, this one also demonstrates the pk case:

**[->SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/76134/1)**

#### Unique index

Both of the above (unique & pk constraints) are implemented by way of a unique index. In addition there can also be **unique indices** doing effectively the same as formally declared unique constraint. To catch **all of them** query the system catalog [`pg_index`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-index.html) instead, in a similar fashion:

```sql
SELECT c.relname AS idx_name
FROM  (
   SELECT indexrelid, string_to_array(indkey::text, ' ')::int[] AS indkey
   FROM   pg_index
   WHERE  indrelid = 'tb'::regclass
   AND    indisunique                    -- contains "indisprimary"
   ) i
JOIN  (
   SELECT array_agg(attnum::int) AS attkey
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = 'tb'::regclass
   AND    attname  = ANY('{c1,c2}')
   ) a ON i.indkey <@ a.attkey AND i.indkey @> a.attkey
JOIN   pg_class c ON c.oid = i.indexrelid;
```

Special difficulty here is the internal type `int2vector`. I deal with it by casting text and converting to `int[]`.

Be aware that implementation of catalog tables might change across major. Unlikely that these queries break, but possible.

Comment: +1, I've almost completed my answer, but yours much more descriptive. Here's sql fiddle for your answer - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e6697/10. One thing I don't really like is capitalized SQL, but I think this is totally subjective :)

Comment: @RomanPekar: It hurts to lose good work just before it's finished. I know the feeling, sorry. Thanks for the fiddle.

Comment: @Anant: I later realised, you may be missing plain unique indices (without explicit constraint). See amended answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out whether a constraint exists (non-portably) by inspecting the `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` table, but that won't tell you whether the constraint *would be violated* by your insert, and it would be prone to races even if it could.

The correct thing to do is to try the insert and handle a failure appropriately.