# Check Constraint Usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, database-design, unique-constraint

I am trying to make a constraint that will keep ids unique for specific users.
Each user is a separate entity within the world so 2 people having 1 as `id` is not a problem.  I just don't want one person to have the same id twice.

For example:
This would be acceptable:

```
User   Id
John   1
John   2
Alice  1
Alice  2
```

This would not be ok:

```
User     Id
John     1
John     1  -- problem
Alice    1
Alice    2
```

Comment: Use `unique constraint` on both `User` and `Id` fields.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE "users" ADD CONSTRAINT "users_unique" UNIQUE ("User", "Id");`

Comment: Why not use the identity property of the column? This way mssql will control the "uniqueness" of the ids of the users, and there is always select count(Id) from user group by username to count the number of johns in the database. In my opinion this is te way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a [Unique constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) over both columns to your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
   ...               -- more columns
   username text 
  ,person_id int
  ,UNIQUE (username, person_id)
);
```

That does it. I see that [@Hamlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154542/check-constraint-useage/20154715#comment30041535_20154542) and [@Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154542/check-constraint-useage/20154715#comment30041538_20154542) already commented likewise.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  Sorry for the check delay. I had to get back to it to try it out.  Would upvote as well, but not enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a unique index on these two columns would also work. This is usually what happens under the covers to enforce the constraint.

Comment: That's the case in Postgres. A unique constraint is implemented using a unique index, plus an entry in in the system catalog table pg_constraint. The constraint is the generally preferred way.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: why is the constraint the preferred way? Is there any downside to using "only" an index?

Comment: The [constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) is the more declarative way - like the SQL standard would suggest it. It is implemented by creating a unique index, plus entries in the system catalogs. Technically, a lowly unique index does the same. [A query like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087259/how-to-find-whether-unique-key-constraint-exists-for-given-columns/20088233#20088233) would depend on the unique constraint being formally declared.

Comment: I am sure the unique index would bristle at being called "lowly", as it would feel it is not getting credit for all the work it does for that constraint guy.  If the constraint columns are being used frequently, adding clustered or include 'baggage' columns *could* help improve query performance.