# How can I test if int2vector contains exactly one specific value?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, types, comparison

My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT
  1
FROM pg_namespace   sch
JOIN pg_class       tab ON tab.relnamespace = sch.oid
JOIN pg_index       idx ON idx.indrelid     = tab.oid
JOIN pg_class       icl ON icl.oid          = idx.indexrelid
JOIN pg_attribute   col ON col.attrelid     = tab.oid
WHERE
      sch.nspname      = 'my_schema'
  AND tab.relkind      = 'r'
  AND idx.indisprimary
  AND icl.relname      = 'pk_my_table'
  AND col.attname      = 'my_table_id'
  AND idx.indkey       = ARRAY[col.attnum] -- <-- The problematic comparison
;
```

This doesn't work, because: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: int2vector = smallint[]`.

I tried various combinations of:

- casting `indkey` to an array like `idx.indkey::smallint[]`
- casting `ARRAY[col.attnum]` to an `int2vector`
- using the `ALL` operator
- using the `@>` operator

How to check whether `indkey` contains exactly one entry which is exactly `col.attnum`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cast to `text` and convert to an `integer` array:

```
AND string_to_array(idx.indkey::text, ' ')::int2[] = ARRAY[col.attnum]
```

Actually, since [`pg_attribute.attnum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-attribute.html) is a `smallint` (`int2`), use `int2[]`.

And since you are only interested in a ***single*** column, you can simplify:

```
AND idx.indkey::text = col.attnum::text
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/99ccf/6)

Careful when dealing with **more than one column** in the index. Consider this related answer:

- [How to find whether unique key constraint exists for given columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087259/how-to-find-whether-unique-key-constraint-exists-for-given-columns/20088233#20088233)

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you can unnest it.

```sql
select unnest('1 2'::int2vector);
```

complete demo:

```sql
begin;
CREATE TABLE multi (my_table_id serial
, name text
, rs int
, CONSTRAINT pk_my_table 
PRIMARY KEY(my_table_id,name)); 

INSERT INTO multi (name, rs) 
VALUES('A', 10),('A', 20),('A', 30),('B', 15),('C', 70),('C', 30);
commit;

SELECT  sub.key, col.attnum
FROM    pg_namespace   sch
JOIN    pg_class       tab ON tab.relnamespace = sch.oid
JOIN    pg_index       idx ON idx.indrelid     = tab.oid
JOIN    pg_class       icl ON icl.oid          = idx.indexrelid
JOIN    pg_attribute   col ON col.attrelid     = tab.oid
CROSS   JOIN    LATERAL  unnest(idx.indkey) sub(key)
WHERE   sch.nspname      = 'public'
AND     idx.indisprimary
AND     icl.relname      = 'pk_my_table'
AND     col.attnum > 0
AND     attisdropped is false
AND     sub.key = attnum
```